# system upgrade data is lost

Tags: upgrade, data-recovery, data-loss

I have lost all my data because of the new update. The installed software is there but all the other folders that I have created are lost.
Is there any way to regain that data?

**OS Name**: Ubuntu 20.04.6LTS x64 bit

Please find the attached screenshot for details:

[image: memory and os details]

Comment: Generally upgrades do not destroy data. What version of Ubuntu did you upgrade from, and what sort of data is missing? Is it files in your home directory?

Comment: Reload your backups.

Comment: I don't know what happened but all the files inside home directories get deleted. My system wallpaper is also get changed automatically. Version: Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS